# Reading in file and Printing price with Product ID

Tags: c#

I have a file that has a product ID (can only be 8 characters) followed by a new line and different prices in ascending order with respect to time on new lines.  I need to print the ProductID and the latest price.

Here is an example of the contents of the file:

```
A1234567
200.000
300.000
B1234567
200.000
400.000
C12345678
100.00
200.00
```

So in this example I need to print:

```
A1234567: 300.00
B1234567: 400.00
```

I've used a regex expression to print the product IDs.  But I can't figure out how to get the latest price.  I was thinking of getting the line before the product ID, but not sure how to do that.

Here is the code I have:

```
    private static void OutputCusipPrice(string filePath)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filePath))
    {
        String s = "";
        Regex r = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
        int pos = 0;

        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (r.IsMatch(s) && s.Length == 8)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            else
            {
                double result;

                if (Double.TryParse(s, out result))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need to cache the previous line. When you get a match then the value you have cached is the latest price for the previous product id. Edge cases to consider include: your cache is empty on the first match and what happens if a product has no prices.

Comment: Those are good cases.  How do I cache the previous line in a readline?

Comment: By cache I just mean store it in a variable. One easy solution would be to declare a variable before the while loop: `string previousLine = null;` and then the last line in the while loop could be `previousLine = s;`.

Comment: your last productid has 9 chars?

Comment: @5a7335h - no, I added C12345678 as a negative case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, Its just an implementation mentioned by @Jason Boyd

```
 private static void OutputCusipPrice(string filePath)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filePath))
        {
            String row = "", current="",previous = "", price = "";
            bool skipInvalid = false; // This is to remove the negative case
            Regex r = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");
            int pos = 0;
            while ((row = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (r.IsMatch(row) && row.Length == 8)
                {
                    current = row;
                    if (previous == "") previous = current;
                    if (current != previous )
                    {
                        previous = row;
                        Console.WriteLine("Price : " + price);
                    }
                    skipInvalid = false;
                    Console.WriteLine(row);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (skipInvalid) continue;
                    double result;
                    if (Double.TryParse(row, out result))
                    {
                        price = result.ToString(); // cache the previous
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        skipInvalid = true;
                    }

                }
            }
            if (previous != "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Price : " + price);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired result.

```
var input = @"A1234567
200.000
300.000
B1234567
200.000
400.000
C1234567
100.00
200.00";
var productIds = Regex.Matches(input, @".{8}\r\n")
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select((m, i) => new { index = i, value = m.Value });

var prices = Regex.Split(input, @".{8}\r\n").Where(r => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r))
                  .Select((r, i) => new { index = i, value = r });

var result = productIds.Join(prices, pro => pro.index, pri => pri.index, (pro, pri) => new {productid = pro.value,prices=Regex.Split(pri.value,@"\r\n")
                        .Where(r => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r))
                        .Reverse().ToArray()[0]});
```